# Setting autocomplete in terminal for NeoVim to behave like Vim

Tags: autocomplete, terminal

I have the files `Test.java` and `Test.class` in the same directory. Something I've noticed is that when I use `Vim` and type `vim T` and press tab in terminal, it autocompletes to `vim Test.java`. But if I were to use `NeoVim`, typing `nvim T` and then tab in terminal would produce `nvim Test.`.

Why is it that `Vim` can automatically detect that I am not going to use choose the `.class` file but `NeoVim` doesn't?

Is there a setting somewhere I can change for `NeoVim` to make it behave like `Vim`? Also is there a setting for `Vim` somewhere in case I want to change its behavior?

I don't think this has anything to do with `set wildignore` in `.vimrc`.

Comment: This behavior isn't related to vim or neovim: it is defined by the shell you use and its completion settings. Unix & Linux is a better place to ask this question.

Comment: tytpe `ps $$` or `echo $SHELL` to understand which shell you are running (probably `bash`). Then find out how to reconfigure its autocompletion

Comment: Auto-completion works differently in different shells. To be able to handle this issue, we need to know exactly what interactive shell you are using on your Unix.

Comment: I posted this in the vi stackexchange, didn't realize it was moved here. I am using `bash` shell.